# I configured everything, but VSCode debugger is not working, why?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, wamp, xdebug, vscode-debugger

VSCode debugger is not working. I installed everything, and my configuration is :

- Windows 10 Pro
- WampServer 3.2.9 (working well, with a green icon)
- PHP 8.1.11 (I use this one, but I have other PHP versions installed on WampServer)
- Apache 2.4.41
- MariaDB 10.4.10
- Xdebug 3.1.5

VSCode debugger was working well before I updated WampServer (from 3.2.0 to 3.2.9) and I added new updates regarding to that. I just followed the wamserver.aviatechno.net instructions, like updating PHP, Apache, MariaDB, MySQL.

So I followed some others communities instructions, for example go to the https://xdebug.org/wizard and use `phpinfo()` function to display all my local server configurations, then copy and paste it on Xdebug's wizard page, and then follow the instruction that given by Xdebug website response. But it didn't work.

I added `xdebug_remote_enable = 1` and `xdebug_autostart = 1` lines in php.ini file, and I updated the environment variable PATH to add the executable PHP path on Windows advanced system, but nothing happens.

So what can be the issue guys ?

Comment: *"I added `xdebug_remote_enable = 1` and `xdebug_autostart = 1` lines in php.ini file"* Those are for Xdebug v2 and do nothing in Xdebug v3. I suggest you check Xdebug upgrade guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide After that you may also want to  check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll check those and I'll come back with a positive result hopefully

Comment: Hello @LazyOne, thanks bro, as I told you, I'll come back with a positif result thanks to you mate, it works perfectly again.

Comment: So I just checked this link [https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide], and I deleted `xdebug_remote_enable=1` and `zend_extension=xdebug` lines that I added manually to php.ini files (of apache and php8), and I updated (added) a new code line at the end of those files, which is `xdebug.mode=debug`.

Again, thanks @LazyOne, I appreciate it mate, enjoy your day bro, have a nice weekend

Comment: So write an answer that other might benefit from. A comment is really not enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked this link [xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide], and I deleted xdebug_remote_enable=1 and zend_extension=xdebug lines that I added manually to php.ini files (of apache and php8), and I updated (added) a new code line at the end of those files, which is xdebug.mode=debug.